# Centering menu items with same width in a horizontal bar with 100% width

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists, centering

I have a small question.
I basicly want to have an `ul` menu in the center, without the gray bar dissapearing.
I tried searching here and most answers have something to do with the css `display` tag but I tried all options and none of them make the menu stand in the middle.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vVH4d/

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav" style="margin:auto">
<ul>
    <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="../info.html">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="../chao.html">Chao</a></li>
    <li><a href="../media.html">Media</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body {background:#192644; margin:0; padding:0;}
#nav {
    font-family: Verdana;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #303030;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    text-align:center;
    font-size:14px;}
#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
       display: block;
       width: 100%; }
#nav li {display: table-cell }
#nav li a {
    width:100px;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #B3B3B3;}
#nav li a:hover {color: #FFF; background-color: #404040; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from

```
#nav li {display: table-cell }
```

to

```
#nav li {display: inline-block }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vVH4d/1/

Comment: The `#nav` element already has `text-align: center;` appended to it, so you don't need to add it to `#nav ul`

Comment: Oops, I skipped the `#nav` element completely.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/vVH4d/3/

You can set the inner `li` tags with: `#nav li { ... display: inline-block; ... }`. This centers all of the menus.

Answer (score 0):

*Simple!* Just change `#nav li {display: table-cell; }` to `#nav li {display: inline-block; }`

**Also, you can remove** `style="margin:auto"` from the `nav` div. It's not needed in this instance. As a general rule of thumb, try and avoid `inline` styling whenever possible and use CSS instead. IMO, the only time `inline` styling should be used is when it's dynamically created via jQuery/js or your creating an email template, etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/vVH4d/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
Try it .It will work fine!
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Margin Auto</title>
    <style>
body {background:#192644; margin:0; padding:0;}
#nav {
    font-family: Verdana;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-color: #303030;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    text-align:center;
    font-size:14px;}
#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%; }
#nav ul li {display: inline-block;}
#nav li a {
    width:100px;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #B3B3B3;}
#nav li a:hover {color: #FFF; background-color: #404040; }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="../info.html">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="../chao.html">Chao</a></li>
    <li><a href="../media.html">Media</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```